# How do i get my accordion panel to auto scroll down when it is opened?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When i open an accordion i want the panel to expand then once it has expanded, i want to html page to auto scroll to panel. For example if i click a panel which when expanded is hidden, how do i make it so my webpage will auto scroll down to the panel?

HTML Code:

```
<button class="accordion">Images</button>
    <div class="panel">
        </div>
    </div>
<button class="accordion">Images</button>
    <div class="panel">
        </div>
    </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
        var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
            acc[i].onclick = function(){
                this.classList.toggle("active");
                this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, you can try something like this:

```
$(".accordion").on("click", function(){
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(this).offset().top }, 'fast');
  return true;
});
```

That will make the web page to scroll to the element when the accordion button is clicked.